# C# MVC simple cart based on session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller

I'm trying to figure out simple cart that stores products in session.

Index View:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.product1)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Add products to cart", "AddToBasket", new { id=item.id})
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Next to each product is "Add to cart" to AddToBasket method in controller which reads the id of the product and store it in the session["basket"] list:

```
public ActionResult AddToBasket(int? id)
{
        if (Session["Basket"] == null)
        {
            Session["Basket"] = new List<int>();
        }

        ((List<int>)Session["Basket"]).Add(id.Value);
        ViewBag.List = Session["Basket"];


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Right now I stored the ids of the products in session and would like to retrieve information from database and match them with ids. And this is something I cannot figure out.
I tried to create dictionary and fill it with values but obviously this didn't work:

```
public ActionResult ShowBasket()
{
    List<int> lista = new List<int>((List<int>)Session["Basket"]);

    Dictionary<int, string> productSet = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    foreach (var product in lista)
    {
        productSet[product] = db.products.Find(product).ToString();
    }

    ViewBag.products = productSet;

    return View(slownik);
}
```

Also tried to ADO.Net to retrieve data from database but failed again:

```
public ActionResult ShowBasket()
{
    List<int> plist = new List<int>((List<int>)Session["Basket"]);

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(my_connection_string);
    SqlCommand myCommand;
    SqlDataReader myReader;
    string s;

    myConnection.Open();
    s = "select product from db.products where id=" + plist[0];
    myCommand = new SqlCommand(s, myConnection);
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (myReader.Read())
    {
        string loaded_record = myReader.GetString("product1");
    }

    myConnection.Close();
    return View();
}
```

Can anyone help on that?
I'm just beginner, after dozen of hours searching for ideas I decided to ask for help as I can't manage that...

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using ADO.Net try using Entity Framework, while it might be an unusual concept at first you basically have an object structure representing your tables. From there writing simple query will get compiled into SQL in the background and executed, and you'll get a result as a strongly typed object. Much simpler to work that way, and less error prone. Looking at the code above there might be several issues, from the manual query you wrote, to how the values in Session are stored or what you get in plist once you initialize it with the Session.

Comment: Could you explain this code:
Dictionary<int, string> productSet = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach (var product in productSet)
{...}

You create a new empty dictionary, and then use it in foreach

Comment: When you say 'this didn't work' can you be more specific?

Comment: Artsion, I did a mistake when copying. in foreach loop I'm using list stored in session and try to fill the dictionary.

Comment: zaitsman, when using the first solution (with new dictionary that I'm trying to fill with values from database) for values I get "Mod9.Models.product". So, 1st element in dictionary has key=0 and value="Mod9.Models.product", 2nd has key=1 and value="Mod9.Models.product". And so on. Instead of "Mod9.Models.product" string I would expect to have there name of the product from database.

Comment: productSet.Add(product,db.products.Find(product).ToString()); ref : [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add Method (TKey, TValue)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: what do you need from this code ? if (myReader.Read())
    {
        string loaded_record = myReader.GetString("product1");
    }

Comment: @beribazoo you are calling ToString() instead of productSet[product] = db.products.Find(product); this is why you see "Mod9.Models.product".

Comment: db.products.Find(product).ToString(); probably ToString() method is not suitable here. If db.products.Find(product) return object from database you should specify correct property name. For example, db.products.Find(product).ProductName

Comment: @ArtsiomMarzavin thanks for this. This is exactly what I was looking for. It also turned out that the logic behind the code was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear specifically what/where your issue is. However it seems to me you never assign your updated list of items back to the session.

In the code below I am specifically saying the session should be updated to the updated list.

```
public ActionResult AddToBasket(int? id)
{
    if (Session["Basket"] == null)
    {
        Session["Basket"] = new List<int>();
    }

    var items = (List<int>)Session["Basket"];
    items.Add(id.Value);
    Session["Basket"] = items;
    ViewBag.List = Session["Basket"];

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

---

There are other *issues* with your code that would find help for over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), be sure to read the [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) first. Here at Stack Overflow we specifically look at errors.

Comment: @Ashley_Medway thanks for pointing Code Review. I will keep it in mind for the next time. You are right that I'm looking for the idea how to do something rather than having error in the code.

Comment: @beribazoo they will help with best practice, etc. but they do have a strict set of rules :)

Answer (score 1):

I can not understand completely what you're trying to achieve, additionally we are missing some pieces of information regarding the view that shows the shopping cart's content, nevertheless I'll try my best to help you.

This solution works for Entity Framework and it's easyly extendable to ADO.NET. I've made some modifications that I hope that help you on your upcoming projects.

ADO Version:

```
public ActionResult ShowBasketADO()
    {
        List<Product> result = new List<Product>();

        List<int> plist = new List<int>((List<int>)Session["Basket"]);
        //We try to be sure that we only make a single query
        string query = "select id, descripcion from products where id in (" + string.Join(",", plist) + ")";
        //Start using IDisposable interface (yes, you can also use it for SqlCommand)
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(cnxString))
        {
            SqlCommand myCommand;
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                Product item = new Product();
                item.Id = (int)myReader[0];
                item.Descripcion = (string)myReader[1];
                result.Add(item);
            }
            myConnection.Close();
        }

        return View(result);
    }
```

EF Solution:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public ActionResult ShowBasket()
    {

        List<int> mylist = new List<int>((List<int>)Session["Basket"]);

        List<Product> IntheCart = new List<Product>();

        foreach (var item in mylist)
        {
            IntheCart.Add(db.Productos.Find(item));

        }
       return View(IntheCart);
      }
```

And the code to render it:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestApp.Models.Product>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowBasket";
}
<h2>ShowBasket</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descripcion)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

If you have any further questions, please, let me know.

Additionally, please check this  [Link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-and-access-447ada98) for a complete tutorial